# possible combinations and loops

Tags: c++

i have to make all possible combinations of a 2d array..for e.g. if i have a array of 4x3 ...i m using 4 loops,all runs up to 3.. to get all combinations...

for.e.g if i have a 4x3 array as given below..

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 
10 11 12
```

i will have to make combinations like

```
1,4,7,10 
1,4,7,11 
1,4,7,12 
1,4,8,10 
1,4,8,11 
1,4,8,12 
1,4,9,10 
1,4,9,11 
1,4,9,12 

1,5,8,10 
1,5,8,11 
1,5,8,12 
...........
```

and so on....

in short all such combinations...the max number of possible combinations in this case will be 3 power 4....and if i have a array of nxm then maximum combinations will be m power n....can any one help creating it....i want help to solve it in generic .....i think recursive function shall be used...as i don't know the no of loop...it will be known during run time...

Comment: These are known as _permutations_. That should give you enough to search for, but look specifically at [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) and its requirements.

Comment: i have seen ur provided link...but it's a different approach....

Comment: Different than what? You've not shown any code..

Comment: void recursive_function(int tasks)
{
  
  if(tasks==0)
  { 
   print();
  }
  
  else
  {
   for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
   {    
    temp[tasks-1][j]=1;   
    recursive_function(tasks-1);   
   }

  }


}

Comment: this what i m trying to do...but not getting my goals

Answer (score 0):

```
void buildArray(vector <int> build, vector< vector <int> > &arrays)
{
    int position = build.size();
    if (position == arrays.size()) { /* current build is one of the solutions*/}
    else {        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays[position].size(); i++) 
        {
            build.push_back(arrays[position][i]);
            buildArray(build, arrays);
            build.pop_back(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: plz tell me when will i print a combination (array )in this code...i mean where?

Comment: You have to replace the comment on line 4. When build.size() == arrays.size() it means you have taken an element from each of the arrays, so you have a solution

Comment: You can print the solution like this: for (int i = 0; i < build.size(); i++) cout << build[i] << " ";

Comment: print a "\n" after that for. You will get to that line once for each row in your 2d array. You are not very good to recursivity, are you?

Comment: @gabitzish : I'd wager he's not very good at _coding_, and is just waiting for you to hand him his completed homework on a silver platter...

Comment: as an  example...the above combination 1,4,7,10 will be printed as ....1 - - -,4 - - -,7 - - -,10, - - -....

Comment: k...what 2 type of arrays do i have to pass it?parameters to function?

Comment: first param is an empty vector<int>, and the second one is a vector of vector<int> representing your input.

Comment: plz answer me...what parameters do i have to transfer to it?

Comment: If you are not accepting my answer, you could at least upvote my answer ... I did spent some time explaining all this to you ...

Comment: as i m dealing with 2d array...i will have to change vectors in to arrays....do u expect any error then?

Comment: i m trying to vote u up but i get a message that u have less reputations...it should be at least 15 to vote up any one...sorry